# Getting ModelForm to insert hidden field for id (preventing duplicate instance on save)

Tags: django-forms

I'm trying to build a simple CUD (Create/Update/Delete) view with a ModelForm, but on save I'm getting a duplicate record:

ModelForm:

```
class formFacetAnswer(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.FacetAnswer
        exclude = ('who')
```

View:

```
def xxx_test1(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = formFacetAnswer(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            answer      = form.save(commit=False)
            answer.who  = request.user
            answer.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    else:
        a_id = request.GET.get('answer')
        if a_id:
            a_id=int(a_id)
            answer = models.FacetAnswer.objects.get(id=a_id)
            form = formFacetAnswer(instance=answer)
        else:
            form = formFacetAnswer()

    return render_to_response('facet_answer.html', dict(form=form), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template:

```
{% extends 'head-plain.html' %}
{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

The `formFacetAnswer(instance=answer)` does not insert a hidden field with the answer ID, so at save time it creates a new one.  What's the best pattern to use for this need, under Django 1.3?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are only passing the instance on GET. If you want to update an existing record on save then you should pass the instance on POST as well.

Answer (score 0):

The "obvious" way when updating ModelForms seems to be having the identifier to the instance of the object in the url.

urls.py:

```
url(r'^answer/(\d+)$', 'app.views.xxx_test1', name='editAnswer'),
url(r'^answer/$',      'app.views.xxx_test1', name='newAnswer '),
```

View:

```
def xxx_test1(request, a_id=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if a_id:
            answer = models.FacetAnswer.objects.get(id=a_id)
            form = formFacetAnswer(request.POST, instance=answer)
        else:
            form = formFacetAnswer(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            answer      = form.save(commit=False)
            answer.who  = request.user
            answer.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    else:
        if a_id:
            answer = models.FacetAnswer.objects.get(id=a_id)
            form = formFacetAnswer(instance=answer)
        else:
            form = formFacetAnswer()

    return render_to_response('facet_answer.html', dict(form=form),    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```